# Python upgrades results in "AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'" error when starting shell

Tags: python-3.x, shell, upgrade, python-3.10

I just upgraded to Python 3.10 on Mac OS X Big Sur.  When I fire up the shell now, I get an error

```
$ python manage.py shell
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 100, in handle
    return getattr(self, shell)(options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 40, in bpython
    bpython.embed()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpython/__init__.py", line 43, in embed
    from .curtsies import main
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpython/curtsies.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .curtsiesfrontend.repl import BaseRepl
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpython/curtsiesfrontend/repl.py", line 34, in <module>
    from bpython.repl import (
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpython/repl.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .paste import PasteHelper, PastePinnwand, PasteFailed
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpython/paste.py", line 24, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .cookies import RequestsCookieJar, cookiejar_from_dict
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/cbapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py", line 174, in <module>
    class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
```

I upgraded to the lateset version of Django, 3.2.9.  Pretty sure my issue is related to the upgrade, but not clear what the error means or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in my project with **request** module.
Seems like MutableMapping moved in the hierarchy into additional abstract class, so in the *python3.10/site-packages/requests/cookies.py*
change

```
class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.MutableMapping):
```

with

```
class RequestsCookieJar(cookielib.CookieJar, collections.abc.MutableMapping):
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).